# Cannot find module 'fs' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, fs

I can't get typescript to recognize 'fs' module.
I get the following error:

```
    Error: src/app/components/drops/drops-map/drops-map.component.ts:9:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs' or its corresponding type declarations.

9 import {readFileSync}  from 'fs';
```

I installed the definitions via:

```
 npm i @types/node --save-dev
```

I checked and the fs.d.ts is correctly placed in node_modules/@types/node folder

this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "node_modules/@types/node"
    ],
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

I deleted the node_modules and reinstalled with npm install with no success.

and lastly this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.35",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
    "@googlemaps/markerclustererplus": "^1.2.8",
    "@zxing/browser": "^0.0.10",
    "@zxing/library": "^0.18.6",
    "@zxing/ngx-scanner": "^3.3.0",
    "firebase": "^9.4.0",
    "rxfire": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.0",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.46.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.37",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3"
  }
}
```

please help

Comment: From the name of the file, it seems like you're trying to use the `fs` module in an Angular component. Unless you're only using `fs` for the server part of server-side rendering of that component (or similar), you can't do that. The `fs` module doesn't exist on the browser, just in Node.js.

Comment: I suspect you need something like `"lib":["node"]` in your `tsconfig` but like T.J.Crowder mentioned this doesn't seem like a normal use case if you are intending for the code to be run on the client side.

Comment: Oh, i see, thanks, that explains everything. :)

Answer (score 4):

What you are missing is in the `tsconfig.json`. You need to add `node` to the types in your typescript's compiler options:

```json
{  
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

So that you have accessed to the node libraries.